# How to make a folder be visible in the calendar view within outlook?

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook-2013, calendar

first I want to excuse for my bad knowledge in the windows world. I am used to Linux and now I was asked to help a windows user.

The problem is in Outlook 2013. There exist several calenders available over CalDAV. Therefore the [Caldav synchronizer](https://sourceforge.net/projects/outlookcaldavsynchronizer/) was installed. This allowed to import a bunch of calendars and put them in some folder. I think it is strange that the calendars are located in folders within an IMAP account but at least these folders are invisible in the mail view if I select that the folders should contain calendars.

In the calendar view of outlook the calendars are shown under the entry `my calendars` (rough translation from German) and the calendars are shown in parallel. They can be enabled/disabled and overlaid and all fancy stuff. OK, no problem so far for 2-3 calendars.

I wanted to add more calendars. I copied the settings in Caldav synchronizer and created a sibling folder to the other calendar folders. I selected the folder to contain calendar events. Interestingly the icon of the folder is not the icon of the other calendars but a plain folder like in the mail folders. When I add the calendar to the folder, the calendar is **not** visible in the calendar view of outlook under `my calendars`. When navigating in the mails view to the parent folder it contains exactly this single folder created earlier. The other sibling calender folders are not visible.
When clicking on the single folder on the right a calendar is shown but still in the mails view. So I cannot enable overlay etc.

The questions are now:

- Can outlook only handle only a few calendars and any more are rejected in the calendar view?
- How can I change the "predicted content" of a folder to be a calendar instead of generic/mail folder?
- How can I hide the folder in the mails view?
- How can I show the folder in the calendar view?

If possible I will provide screenshots tomorrow as soon as I can ask my college to do so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be honest I do not know how the problem was solved. I guess this was due to the daily reboot of the machine (shutdown at end of day and start next morning). The calendar folders are marked as such and are visible in the calendar view of outlook.

Quite strange but it seems to be solved...